# Is it necessary to build a wear app to track activities (Eg. Running, walking, swimming, Hiking, Cycling etc) and to send data to android mobile app?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to fetch user activity() statistics (calories, distance, pace, Elevation, lap time) on google wear watches to a mobile application is it compulsory to build wear OS application to send data to mobile application.